# How to prevent application ruuning when there is emergency update on applicatin version

Tags: java, android, react-native, version

I want to prevent users to open application when there is emergency updates for the application and make user to update the application to open and run it successfully. The easiest way to solve this problem for me is implementing a simple version check to check the current version and last published version from server. But I think it might be a common requirement between android developers so if you mind to let me know if there are any react-native library in that developed to solve this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is the correct, check serverside if the version is the correct, if not, you can handle different approaches to prevent running.

Take the user to a "update required" page with no exit.

Show an alert with no buttons and cancellable:true [only tested on android]

Disable the apis used making the app unavailable
Etc